# Is it possible for a trait to return trait objects specified by a generic type on the trait?

Tags: rust

I would like to define a trait like this:

```
pub trait Provider<T> {
    fn load(&self, name: &str) -> Box<dyn T>;
}
```

But it is not possible:

```
error[E0404]: expected trait, found type parameter `T`
 --> src/lib.rs:2:47
  |
2 |         fn load(&self, name: &str) -> Box<dyn T>;
  |                                               ^ not a trait
```

A possible solution is to remove the `dyn` keyword, but I want implementors of `Provider` to return trait objects, like this:

```
pub struct MaterialProvider {}

trait Material {}

impl Provider<Material> for MaterialProvider {
    fn load(&self, name: &str) -> Box<dyn Material> { /*...*/ }
}
```

Is it possible to express such a concept?

I wanted to use this to create a single "resource repository" which can be used to create Objects of varying types. The exact types which should be supported might not be known at compile time and they don't necessarily need to implement the same interface.

In C++ one way to solve the described problem is like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class A {
  public:
    static std::string identifier()  {
        return "A";
    }
};

class B {
  public:
    static std::string identifier()  {
        return "B";
    }
};

class ProviderBase {};

template <typename T>
class Provider : public ProviderBase {
  public:
    virtual T* load() = 0;
};

class ProviderA : public Provider<A> {
  public:
    A* load() {
        return new A;
    }
};

class Manager {
    std::map<std::string, ProviderBase*> providers;

  public:
    template<typename T>
    void register_provider(Provider<T>* provider) {
        providers[T::identifier()] = provider;
    }

    template<typename T>
    T* load() {
        auto p = providers.find(T::identifier());

        if (providers.end() != p) {
            return static_cast<Provider<T>*>(p->second)->load();
        }

        return nullptr;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Manager m;

    ProviderA provider_a;

    m.register_provider(&provider_a);

    if (m.load<A>()) {
        std::cout << "Loaded A" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Could not load A" << std::endl;
    }

    if (m.load<B>()) {
        std::cout << "Loaded B" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Could not load B" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does `MaterialProvider` implement `Material`?

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In your attempt to solve your problem, you try to have a generic parameter that can be filled by a trait. This is not possible in today's Rust. While I certainly want this feature in Rust, I think your actual problem can be solved without that feature by using a completely different approach. This `Manager`/`Provider` stuff doesn't seem to me like it would be useful/necessary in Rust. Maybe you can tell us a bit more about the actual problem by [edit]ing the question?

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios, `MaterialProvider` does not implement `Material`.

Comment: @B_old Do you want this kind of stuff? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=74f06743bf89ab87dbe93f02274fe93a

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt, I will think about a concise description of what I want in plain english. In the meantime I included example code of what I would be using in C++, that hints at the use case at the very end.

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios, I think that solves part of my problem. I will have to study it some more, thanks!

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios I think it would be more obvious if you used the `dyn` syntax everywhere (e.g. `impl Provider<dyn Material>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic trait may be parameterized on a type, but not on another trait.  So in `trait Provider<T>`, `T` is a type, not a trait, which means there’s no such thing as `dyn T`.

But a type parameter should be all you need here, if the type is itself allowed to be a trait object type.  To allow this, you just need to suppress the default `Sized` bound, since trait objects are unsized:

```rs
pub trait Provider<T: ?Sized> {
    fn load(&self, name: &str) -> Box<T>;
}

pub struct MaterialProvider {}

trait Material {}

impl Provider<dyn Material> for MaterialProvider {
    fn load(&self, name: &str) -> Box<dyn Material> { /* ... */ }
}
```